# Is it possible to get detailed help on a given function using the command line?

Tags: python

I am a new Python user :)
Is it possible to get detailed help on a given function using the command line ?

Comment: What command line?  Python's `>>>` prompt?  Or some other random command line?  If so, which other command line?

Answer (score 4):

As python tells you when you start the CLI:

> ```
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>>
> ```

just ask for [help](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#help):

```
help(help)
help(list)
help(locals)
import math
help(math)
help(math.atan2)
```

Comment: @NaimeYidwen: note that SO uses a Q&A, rather than forum, format. Comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. To thank someone, you can up-vote their answer. If your question is resolved, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) one answer, which lets everyone know that more answers aren't needed, recommends the answer to others with the same issue and rewards the answerer with reputation.

Comment: ...  When you get an answer that resolves your issue, it's best to wait a few days before accepting in case a better one comes in. Don't worry about accepting answers for unresolved questions.

Answer (score 3):

Consider installing [IPython](http://ipython.org). Not only does it give you quick and easy access to [help doc strings](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#exploring-your-objects):

```
In [3]: os.path.expanduser?
Type:       function
Base Class: <type 'function'>
String Form:    <function expanduser at 0xb77ffe64>
Namespace:  Interactive
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
Definition: os.path.expanduser(path)
Docstring:
    Expand ~ and ~user constructions.  If user or $HOME is unknown,
    do nothing.
```

it also helps you find out what attributes / methods an object has through [tab completion](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#tab-completion):

```
os.path.__name__                    os.path.ismount
os.path.__new__                     os.path.join
os.path.__package__                 os.path.lexists
os.path.__reduce__                  os.path.normcase
os.path.__reduce_ex__               os.path.normpath
os.path.__repr__                    os.path.os
os.path.__setattr__                 os.path.pardir
os.path.__sizeof__                  os.path.pathsep
os.path.__str__                     os.path.realpath
os.path.__subclasshook__            os.path.relpath
os.path._resolve_link               os.path.samefile
os.path._varprog                    os.path.sameopenfile
os.path.abspath                     os.path.samestat
os.path.altsep                      os.path.sep
os.path.basename                    os.path.split
os.path.commonprefix                os.path.splitdrive
os.path.curdir                      os.path.splitext
os.path.defpath                     os.path.stat
os.path.devnull                     os.path.supports_unicode_filenames
os.path.dirname                     os.path.sys
os.path.exists                      os.path.walk
os.path.expanduser                  os.path.warnings

In [4]: os.path.[TAB]
```

On Debian/Ubuntu, ipython can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install ipython
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean using the shell command line, here is a possible solution:

```
python -c "help(help)"
```

Answer (score 0):

For most modules:

```
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Sep 23 2011, 00:28:08) 
....
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> help(os)

>>> print os.__doc__
OS routines for Mac, NT, or Posix depending on what system we're on.

This exports:
  - all functions from posix, nt, os2, or ce, e.g. unlink, stat, etc.
  - os.path is one of the modules posixpath, or ntpath
  - os.name is 'posix', 'nt', 'os2', 'ce' or 'riscos'
  - os.curdir is a string representing the current directory ('.' or ':')
  - os.pardir is a string representing the parent directory ('..' or '::')
  - os.sep is the (or a most common) pathname separator ('/' or ':' or '\\')
  .....
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Python command prompt then:

```
help(whatever)
```

or if `whatever` is a reserved word:

```
help("whatever")
```

If you mean the shell or windows command prompt then use pydoc:

```
C:\Python32>lib\pydoc.py json.dumps
Help on function dumps in json:

json.dumps = dumps(obj, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, s
eparators=None, default=None, **kw)
    Serialize ``obj`` to a JSON formatted ``str``.

    If ``skipkeys`` is false then ``dict`` keys that are not basic types
    (``str``, ``int``, ``float``, ``bool``, ``None``) will be skipped
    instead of raising a ``TypeError``.

    If ``ensure_ascii`` is false, then the return value can contain non-ASCII
    characters if they appear in strings contained in ``obj``. Otherwise, all
    such characters are escaped in JSON strings.

    If ``check_circular`` is false, then the circular reference check
    for container types will be skipped and a circular reference will
    result in an ``OverflowError`` (or worse).

    If ``allow_nan`` is false, then it will be a ``ValueError`` to
    serialize out of range ``float`` values (``nan``, ``inf``, ``-inf``) in
    strict compliance of the JSON specification, instead of using the
    JavaScript equivalents (``NaN``, ``Infinity``, ``-Infinity``).

    If ``indent`` is a non-negative integer, then JSON array elements and
    object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent
    level of 0 will only insert newlines. ``None`` is the most compact
    representation.

    If ``separators`` is an ``(item_separator, dict_separator)`` tuple
    then it will be used instead of the default ``(', ', ': ')`` separators.
    ``(',', ':')`` is the most compact JSON representation.

    ``default(obj)`` is a function that should return a serializable version
    of obj or raise TypeError. The default simply raises TypeError.

    To use a custom ``JSONEncoder`` subclass (e.g. one that overrides the
    ``.default()`` method to serialize additional types), specify it with
    the ``cls`` kwarg; otherwise ``JSONEncoder`` is used.
```

Comment: Than you ! It works ! I am about the Python command prompt :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pydoc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/pydoc.1.html)